# Select radiobutton with python urllib2

Tags: python, radio-button, urllib2

I'm trying to select a radiobuton from this form with python urllib2 and submit the form through a button:

```
<div id="show-form2" class="show-form2">
<input type="radio" name="2" value="21"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="22"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="23"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="24"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="25"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="26"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="27"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="28"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="29"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="30"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="31"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="32"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="33"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="34"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="35"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="36"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="37"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="38"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="39"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="2" value="40"/>
OPTION 
<br/>
```

I'm a little lost in this task, and the info I found is related to use mechanize. Is there a way to get this done with python standard libraries?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You don't "select" things with urllib2, because it doesn't have anything to do with a browser. Instead you need to construct the data that would be sent by the form, and post it directly:

```
import urllib, urllib2
data = urllib.urlencode({'2': '22'}) # assume you want to select the value "22"
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print result.read()
```

If there are other fields, you can add them inside the dictionary that you pass to `urlencode`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have to click a button before selecting the radiobutton. This is the html code for the button `<input type="button" class="poll-wh-style" value="votar" onclick="javascript:vote_poll_sc(2)"/>` Should it be added to the dictionary typing the value?

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means.

Comment: I mean how could I "click" the button through the script before checking the radiobutton

Comment: You'll need to post the HTML for that, and explain how it relates to the radio button.