# How to convert a URL Request into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access the "Yield Curve Data" available on [this page](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/). It has radio button which upon clicking "Submit" results in a CSV File, from which I am looking to get the data. I am looking to get the data from the "Retrieve all data" Option. I want to convert this data into a `dataframe`. However, I don't know how to convert the `result` which is `<addinfourl at 149347464L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000008E55660>>` into a `dataframe`.

```
import urllib, urllib2
import csv
import urllib2
import StringIO
import pandas as pd
my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/'
data = urllib.urlencode({'lastchange': 'all'}) 
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print result #Output: <addinfourl at 149347464L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000008E55660>>
```

**Edit**: In reference to Kevin Zhao's question, part of the output is as given below. Also, I'm using the same idea as is given in the Answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492536/select-radiobutton-with-python-urllib2). However, capturing the data upon Submitting the form appears to be the issue:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: could you try to put this code at the bottom? `print result.read()` and show us the result of that line?  This might help debug...

Comment: @KevinZhao Thank You. I have posted a portion of the output from the line you suggested

Comment: so you are trying to grab data from a website or a csv file downloaded from the site after you click a button?

Comment: you are opening the web page, not the data file.  I would suggest inspecting the button in chrome dev tools (or similar) to see if you can figure out the url that the button requests from.

Comment: @KevinZhao I am trying to grab data from the CSV File downloaded from the site after I click the button.

Comment: @ChristopherPearson Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I am using the same idea as given in the Answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492536/select-radiobutton-with-python-urllib2 . I can't understand how mine is any different.

Comment: The url in your code `http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/` points to the webpage with the button, but you are expecting it to be the csv document.  if you actually read the code for the webpage, you will see that the button submits a post to the url `http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv` which is what I think you want once you figure out what the post should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! So if I understood you correctly, you want to open a page, click on a button on the page, then have a file downloaded?  If that's the case, using selenium might work better than urllib2, see this link for information on how to use it:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1nk0r4/python_library_for_automating_interaction_with_a/

Comment: Then you can open csv file to grab data

Comment: Thanks. But I get the impression both `splinter` and `selenium` can only be used with Firefox? However, I need code that would be more flexible.

Comment: umm, it supports a lot of different browsers actually http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp

Comment: But it doesn't support Google Chrome from what I can tell. However, thats the browser I'm using.

Comment: you are right, splinter might not work with splinter, but selenium has another package that will work, which is shown in the link above...

Comment: Thanks. I've written this code: `from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(15) # wait's for the page to get done loading before it does anything with it
driver.get('http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv')
search = br.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Submit"]')
search.click()

#get restults
search = br.find_element_by_name('nameOfField')
result = str(search.text)` but am now facing the error `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH` in the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`. Could you please help?

Comment: @user131983, you should make that last comment a new question.  Try not to use questions/comments as running dialog.

Comment: agreed with @ChristopherPearson, if you want to mark my answer as correct to this question, that would be awesome, then it would be great if you can ask another question, and post the link here, at the mean time, I will look into the issue :-)