# Converting zipped CSV File into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access the "Yield Curve Data" available on [this page](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/). The code below does this, but I am then trying to convert the zipped CSV File obtained into a Dataframe. The code below works upto the part when I want to convert the zipped file into a Dataframe. I get the Error `df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(zipfile.namelist())` in the line `df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(zipfile.namelist())`. I was wondering how to circumvent this issue.

```
import urllib, urllib2
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pprint import pprint, pformat

my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv'
data = urllib.urlencode({"lookupPage": "lookup_yield_curve.php",
                         "startRange": "1986-01-01",
                         "searchRange": "all"})
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
zipdata = result.read()
zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(zipdata))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(zipfile.namelist())
print df
```

Thank You

Comment: You didn't actually show us what the error is.

Comment: You are making some progress I see over your [past question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30851991/4530863).  Can you post the full text of the error traceback so we can assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zipfile.namelist` just returns a list of filenames -- it does not actually extract anything (https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist).

This should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[0]))
```